# Changed URL in worldpress openshift site. Now I can't login. How do I get back in?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, authentication, openshift

I have a wordpress site that I created using OpenShift apps. I had been using it fine. However, today I went into my Admin login and changed both the Wordpress address and site name, to add "www" as a prefix.

However, now I can't login back to the admin section.

How can I get back in there?

Also, what would be the proper way to eventually add the 'www' prefix to it?

OpenShift doesn't offer FTP or PHPMyAdmin as far as I know, so that's not an option, as per the official site page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

I'm attaching a screenshot of the error code I get when I try to log in. It says ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT[Wordpress Admin Connection Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkIyI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think they offer SFTP, just change the port from 21 to 22 and you can connect ,  after that you need to download phpmyadmin and upload it then you need to get the DB username and password from wp-config.php to login , after that you can change the url.

I have a trick for you , I don't know if it's working but you can try.

first you need to know your website ip.

then edit windows host file and add www.example.com then your website ip.

after that I think you can login again and fix everything

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an alias with www.yourwebsite.com even if you already have yourwebsite.com as an alias.
2. Use cloudflare DNS system (cloudflare.com), you can use their CDN service if you want aswell but it's all up to you. You might have to change your dns to cloudflare's DNS, it can take 24 hours for DNS propagation.
3. Create a CNAME to point yourwebsite.com to 174.129.25.170 that's http://wwwizer.com/ service to redirect yourwebsite.com to www.website.com. It's free and no registration needed. And then point www to yourapp.rhcloud.com.
4. Openshift allow you to add phpmyadmin to your cartridge, login in https://www.openshift.com/ add phpmyadmin (login and password will be auto generated)
5. https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL follow the steps and change your website url to http://www.yourwebsite.com in both fields.
6. It will work now, but if you have problems with redirect loop when trying to login in your /wp-admin. You'll have to change your wp-config.php file. Just put this there: define( 'force_SSL', true ); this will disable ssl for admin area and fix the redirect loop problem.

Step 2 is optional, you can use your domain registrar and point A record to wwwizer and www to yourapp.rhcloud.com